# How to enhance Java pattern so it includes special characters around the match as well?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
*to *make/to *have *a *dab *at *smb. (\*dictionary) some text without special symbols at the begging.
```

Goal is to extract the words with leading `*` symbol from the string and here is the way i do it:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[*]\\s*(\\w+)").matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        phrase += matcher.group(1) + " ";
    }
```

Output looks like this:

```
to make have a dab at smb dictionary
```

I do understand why parenthesis are not included (they do not match pattern), but can someone explain to me why `/to` part is not matched?

Is there anyway to enhance my pattern so it includes special characters around the match(if they exist) as well?

**Expected output:**

```
to make/to have a dab at smb. (dictionary)
```

Comment: Because `\w` means any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. You need to use `\S` instead which means any non-whitespace character but care it matches `)` as well.

Comment: @revo you are right, thank you for your remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with 2 capturing groups for finding all the non-whitespace text, next and prior to `*`

```
(\S*)\*\s*(\S+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RllQI2/2)

You need to combine `.group(1)` an `.group(2)` inside the `while` loop.

For Java use this regex declaration:

```
final String regex = "(\\S*)\\*\\s*(\\S+)";
```

Comment: Why two groups?

Comment: Because OP wants to grab non-space characters before `*` as well e.g. `(dictionary)` in expected output.

Comment: With this idea, you are taking into account any `\S` characters after `\*\s*` but not any `\S` characters before `\s*\*`. It means `( \* dictionary)` is a partial match.

Comment: With limited information in a not-so-well-formatted question, we have to go by an example provided. If it doesn't meet OP's requirement then I will tweak it.

Comment: @anubhava, thank you for your answer it works great, but can you explain the part about two groups? In my example just one group works fine or should i expect some edge cases?

Comment: Absolutely right but the one who brought the idea to the table was you.

Comment: @revo just read your comment here, now i understand what you say, but in my inputs i can guarantee that there will not be any * followed by white space so answer works fine in given example(and in all my input t.b.h), but thanks again

Comment: @iColdBeZero: I used a group with `\S*` before `*` so that we can match text like `(*dictionary)` where `(` comes before `*`